# Script that returns _id in MongoDB with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need a javascript code that saves in a variable the **_id** I'm having trouble getting that **_id** because it’s inside an array.

I have looked everywhere but I can't find a solution for this.

```
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "626bacea1847f675e47b2bd8"
    },
    "tipo": "conta",
    "data_abertura": {
      "$date": "2013-02-19T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "observacoes": "Sem observações",
    "iban": "PT50000506515926456299903",
    "saldo": 1456.23,
    "bic": "BBPIPTPL001",
    "tipo_conta": "Conta Ordenado",
    "cartoes": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "626bacea1847f675e47b2bd7"
        },
        "num_cartao": 4908509005925727,
        "nome_cartao": "João Correia",
        "validade": {
          "$date": "2025-10-03T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "pin": 5609,
        "cvc": 975,
        "estado": "Ativo",
        "tipo_cartao": "Crédito"
      }
    ],
    "permissoes": {
      "levantamentos": true,
      "depositos": true,
      "pagamentos": true,
      "transferencias": true,
      "creditos": true,
      "acoes": true
    },
    "titulares": [
      {
        "$oid": "626bacea1847f675e47b2bd6"
      }
    ]
  }
```

**I want the cartoes _id**

```
"cartoes": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "626bacea1847f675e47b2bd7"
        },
```

I want something like this:

```
let conta = db.banco.findOne({"tipo": "conta"});
idConta = conta._id;

console.log("id: " + idConta);//id: 626bacea1847f675e47b2bd8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

According to the comments, I understand you want to input `num_cartao` value and to get an output of the _id of this `cartao`. You can use an aggregation for this:

```
const cartao_id = await db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {cartoes: {$elemMatch: {"num_cartao": 4908509005925727}}}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      cartoes: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$cartoes",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item.num_cartao", 4908509005925727]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$cartoes", 0]}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {$toString: "$data._id"}
    }
  }
])

console.log(`cartao_id: ${cartao_id}`);//id: 626bacea1847f675e47b2bd7
```

That will provide you what you want, as you can see on this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-fA9TGNJL5k)

You first `$match` the documents with the right `num_cartao`, then `$filter` the right carto from the `cartoes` array, and then you format it to string.

Comment: Yes that query gives me an object, now how can I extract that **_id** and save it in a variable?

Comment: It returns what you asked for...Do you want just the id? since it is an array, there can be more than one id...Another question is where do you want to save it? on the mongodb or on your RAM?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain my self clearly I want something like in the query I pass the **num_cartao** and it gives me his **_id** that I than save in a variable to be used in the future check te question I edited so it can be a little more clear. If you have any questions just ask and thanks for the help.

Comment: Edited the answer and the playground example. Is this answering to your request? If not please explain.

Comment: I can see that you are very skilled in MongoDB by the query that you made but what I want is to save that **id** in a local variable like I showed in the example where **idConta** contains the **id**.

Comment: Is this what you were missing?